# Ansible loop through group vars to templating prometheus.yml

Tags: ansible, jinja2, prometheus

I´m trying to use jinja2 to templating prometheus.yml in a deployment using Ansible.

I got a prometheus server and 3 exporters. This is my host file

```
[prometheus-server]
promserver.domain.es

[prometheus-exporter]
exporter01.domain.es      spring_port='["20001", "20002"]'  
exporter02.domain.es      spring_port='["20001", "20002"]'  
exporter03.domain.es      spring_port='["20001"]'
```

My goal is to get a prometheus.yml thas looks like this

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s  # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s  # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s)

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'Prometheus_Monitoring'

# Load and evaluate rules in this file every 'evaluation_interval' seconds.
rule_files:
  - "alert.rules"



# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape.
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 10s
  static_configs:
   - targets: ['promserver.domain.es:9090']

- job_name: 'spring-actuator-20001'
  metrics_path: '/prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
   - targets: ['exporter01.domain.es:20001' , 'exporter02.domain.es:20001' , 'exporter03.domain.es:20001' ]


- job_name: 'spring-actuator-20002'
  metrics_path: '/prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
   - targets: ['exporter01.domain.es:20002' , 'exporter02.domain.es:20002' ]
```

I want to deploy prometheus templating prometheus.yml, so I´m using jinja2 to get prometheus.yml.j2 using the next code

```
{% for port in groups[prometheus-exporter.{{ spring_port }}] %}
- job_name: 'spring-actuator-{{ port }}'
  metrics_path: '/prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
   - targets: [{% for host in groups[prometheus-exporter]  %}'{{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}:{{ port }}'{{ '' if loop.last else ','}}{% endfor %}]

{% endfor %}
```

but is not working properly to get the expected result.

Any ideas for the code necesary to get the correct prometheus.yml ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a bit more complicated than you expected.

You will first need to get a list of unique configured ports for your exporters to loop on.

Then for each port iteration, you will need to select the exporters which have the corresponding port configured.

The below solution is combining several ansible/jinja2 filters and concepts. Explaining each of them goes beyond this single answer and you will have to look at the different documentation to go further.

**Note**: using dashes (`-`) in group names is deprecated. You must replace them with underscores (`_`). I fixed that in the test inventory I used and that change is also reflected in my below example template.

```
{% set port_list = groups.prometheus_exporter | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('spring_port', 'defined') | map(attribute='spring_port') | flatten | unique | sort %}
{% for port in port_list %}
- job_name: 'spring-actuator-{{ port }}'
  metrics_path: '/prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
   - targets: ['{{ groups.prometheus_exporter | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('spring_port', 'defined') | selectattr('spring_port', 'contains', port) | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | map('regex_replace', '(^.*$)', '\g<1>:' + port) | join("', '") }}']
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great¡ That solucition almost fullfit my requirements.  But I got a problem if the host don´t have de spring_port variable. In that case a got this message  **"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'spring_port'"**  Is there a way that the template only use the hosts that got the spring_port variable ?

Comment: Just updated the answer so that it will not fail if the var does not exists.

Comment: Marvelous. That code completely fulfill my requirements. The template build as I want it . I need to found info of how to code with that jinja2 filters.  BR.

Comment: If this is fixing your issue, you should accept the answer (green tick) to let other users know there is a working solution.